# Link in Russian (Cyrillic) in a pdf document to an external pdf document

Tags: pdf

I want to create a reference document in latex, which will contain clickable links to other documents that are stored on my computer in **different** places.

The fact is that links and documents must contain the full path to it, and therefore they contain **Cyrillic** characters.

I was looking for answers to this question, but I could not find a solution for myself.
I tried to translate Russian links using a converter, but I got a lot of  *"%"* signs, which Latex recognizes as a comment. In any case, this method is terribly long and not working.

Is there a universal solution to this problem?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[unicode, pdftex]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\href{D:/Содержание/Практика.pdf}{Задание смотри здесь}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem that you encounter with the code in your question? Do you get errors during compilation? Is the Cyrillic not shown? Is the link not created/not clickable? Does it lead to a missing file? Does it work for a file in the same folder but not a file with a full path? Does it work for files with Latin characters with a full path but not for Cyrillic? Please be as specific as possible.

Comment: Note also that it might be viewer-dependent how this kind of links are handled - do you get the same result in different pdf viewers?

Comment: Everything works when you specify the full path in the Latin alphabet.  But I have no way to rename all the folders to the Latin alphabet.  When specifying the path in Cyrillic, the link is created, but when you click on it, the file is not found

Comment: Some pdf viewers accept percent-encoded links for local files. You could try `\href{D:/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0.pdf}{Задание смотри здесь}`.

Comment: I tried it but it didn't help. The link is being created, but the specified file could not be found by the pdf viewers